# Bad Access on removing from array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So my code compiles and when i run my iphone app in xcode it crashes spewing out a ton of memory errors complaining about bad accesses which i have no idea what that means.All iam trying to do is remove the labes i create from my super view using a counter in an array which turn out to be infinitely harder than i imagined. I am very new to object c and iphone development any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> 
{
    /*This stuff creates a timer */
    IBOutlet UILabel *opponentsBlue;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int redBlue;
    int count;
    /*Stuff for making a label creator */
    CGPoint startPoint;
    int xStuff, yStuff;

    /*array for storing wards*/
    NSMutableArray *wardArray;

}

@property CGPoint startPoint;

- (IBAction)startRedBlue:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)removeWard:(id)
sender;
- (void)countdown;
-(id)init;

@end

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize startPoint;

- (void)countdown 
{
    if (redBlue < 2) {

        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    redBlue -= 1;
    opponentsBlue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", redBlue];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.view];

}

-(id)init{
    int count = 0;
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)startRedBlue:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *wardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    wardButton.frame = CGRectMake((startPoint.x - 5), (startPoint.y - 5), 10, 10);
    [wardButton setTitle:@"180" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //add targets and actions
    /*[wardButton addTarget:self action:@selector() forControlEvents:<#(UIControlEvents)#>*/
    //add to a view
    [self.view addSubview:wardButton];

    if (!wardArray) {
        wardArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    } 
    if (wardArray){
        [self->wardArray addObject: wardButton];
        count++;
    }

    NSLog(@"This elemnt = %@", wardArray);


}
- (IBAction)removeWard:(id)sender 
{

    NSLog(@"The count is %@", count);
    [[wardArray objectAtIndex:count] removeFromSuperview];

    count--;

    NSLog(@"This elemnt = %@", wardArray);


}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Show the exact error messages and/or crash reports you're seeing and, assuming the debugger stops your program, show which line in your code it's showing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the guess that this is not ARC (Automatic Reference Count).

wardArray is not being retain, hence it is deallocated soon after it's created.

You can try replacing `[NSMutableArray array]` with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`. That way it will only leak memory instead of leaving a zombie around.

Also you may want to read up on Objective-C memory management.

Comment: turns out the problem was me trying to print the counter using NSLOG thanks for the help though